# Past participle phrase and passive voice

Tags: past-participles, passive-voice

Are they both correct and have the same meaning?

1. The cake eaten by Joe is delicious.
2. The cake was eaten by Joe is delicious.

I found this sentence in learning past participle phrase.

The boy taken to hospital has recovered.

Taken to hospital is a past participle phrase. Why we don't add "was" before taken, I think the boy was taken to hospital. In a passive voice, it should add "was"  to it.

Comment: I'm not sure of the proper explanation for it, but 1 is always preferred here.  "*eaten by Joe*" is a shortened form of "*that was eaten by Joe*" (or *who was taken to hospital* in your second example.)  The long version and the short version are entirely appropriate, but there is no middle ground.

Comment: _The boy **who** was taken to the hospital has recovered_ would make sense to a native speaker.

Answer (score 1):

You are right that in passive voice we use *was* (or any other form of the verb *be*) and a past participle. This means we can create phrases like these:

> The cake that was eaten by Joe was delicious.
>
> The boy who was taken to hospital has recovered.

You will notice that both of the sentences above contain a relative clause (i.e. that was eaten/who was taken), that we can reduce to remove the pronoun and *be* verb form. We do this to be more economical in our expression. That means the following sentences are equally valid:

> The cake eaten by Joe was delicious.
>
> The boy taken to hospital has recovered.

Your mistake was to not add "who/what" to describe the boy.

Some more information on participle clauses can be found [here on the BBC](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv305.shtml).

Comment: Unfortunately you have a few errors in your sentence. If you have further questions, please ask a new question.

Comment: "My heart was broken by the promises she failed to fulfil". Only one of the two verbs works in passive.